# New to webdev and need a direction for online store setup with the PayPal button

Tags: integration, paypal-buttons

longtime stackoverflow searcher and I am usually finding everything I need without asking, well I guess I need an advice.

I have a little website almost ready to go. 
I have business PayPal account and I already created a "Buy it now" button.

I need a direction where to look and what to research to accomplish what I need.
Let's say I am selling 100 different items. 
All items are leading to one or two "Buy it now" buttons.
How should I learn what user have purchased?

Need research directions, maybe ideas what to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas that may help. Any e-commerce related website/application offers product catalogs. Each item is display and, there is generally a "Add to Cart" button that, allows user to select multiple products before proceeding to checkout. In order to this, sites like Amazon, ebay and others enforce that user's logs in to site. This means, each customer purchasing on your site must have an account. You can then store the user's details and transaction histories in a database and, proceed from there. 
This is one of the most widely practiced method of payment process on e-commerce (as far as I have seen). Consider making your button a "Add to cart" button instead of "Buy Now". Why? If the user wants to buy multiple products (assuming your application allows that) then, with a button for every item, they will have to click on the button and, go through the entire checking out process for each product they wish to buy. This is undesirable. Instead, add a shopping cart and a checkout option. It will be much simpler.

As for directions, it is entirely dependent on what stack you are using. Based on the language, framework, check to see if, there are existing packages that already implements such functionalities and use them wherever possible. For a list of topics, consider looking into Paypal integration from the Paypal website and other online resources, creating and authenticating users, adding shopping cart support, cataloging products (if not already done), creating products database (if not done).

No way this is an exhaustive list! This should be good to get you going with your development.
Start with this if you haven't looked at it already: [Paypal Checkout Inegration](https://developer.paypal.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much, will look into PayPal integration.